How I change dynamic value of class css in Angular17
I try to change dynamic value in a class; in React it is very easy but I newbie in Angular and I don't know how to do it.
enter image description here HTML file contains value (columns)  I want to change
enter image description here TS file, I define value is @input, I want value columns will be receive value from parent
NOTE: I use Tailwind CSS to style the HTML
I tried to search the docs for Angular 17, but I didn't see what I want.

To change you use interpolation or binding or structural directive like ngClass
//interpolation
  <div class="grid grid-columns-"+{{columns}}>..</div>

//binding
  <div [class]="'grid grid-columns-'+columns">..</div>

//ngClass
  <div [ngClass]="'grid grid-columns-'+columns">..</div>

See that ngClass you can use in several ways -in this case you use simple as [ngClass]="expresion" that it's like binding class

You can use ngClass
Make sure you have the imports either NgClass or CommonModule are required to use this directive!
<div class="grid" [ngClass]="'grid-cols-'+columns">
    ...
</div>

Code
import { NgClass } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgClass],
  styles: [
    `
    .grid-cols-1 {
      color: red;
    }
    .grid-cols-2 {
      color: blue;
    }
  `,
  ],
  template: `
    <div class="grid" [ngClass]="'grid-cols-'+columns">
      Hello from {{ name }}!
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  columns = 1;
  name = 'Angular';

  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.columns = this.columns === 1 ? 2 : 1;
    }, 1000);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz

You need to import "NgClass" in your product.component.ts file, like below
import { NgClass } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgClass],
  styles: ['...'],
  template: `...`,
})

then you can reference to angular document to see how to use [ngClass] attribute to create dynamic styles on html.
